# Since Google map's <script> tag does not read create-react-app's public/index.html file, what library could I use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, create-react-app

I've been working with a course online using Webpack & Googlemaps, and I need to bring it to my Create-React-App application but I know create-react-app doesn't read script tags with api keys in the public/index.html file. Is there a work around instead of using google maps npm packages? I truly would appreciate any tips in the right direction.

Here is my script tag with the API_KEY :

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='API_KEY'">
</script>
```

Here's my google maps object inside my componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount(){

  const {properties, activeProperty} = this.props;

  const {latitude, longitude} = activeProperty;

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
      mapTypeControl: false,
      zoom: 14
  });

  this.createMarkers(properties);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage Google Maps library parameters, instead of referencing Google Maps library via `index.html` you could consider to load script resources on-demand like [some popular libraries](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) do.

For example, with [`ReactDependentScript` component](https://github.com/shaneosullivan/ReactDependentScript) Google Maps API could be loaded like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {

    const MAP_KEY = "--YOUR-KEY-GOES-HERE--";

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactDependentScript scripts={[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${MAP_KEY}`]}>
          <Map center={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} zoom={3} />
        </ReactDependentScript>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mcyzkp) for your reference

Comment: Thanks a whole lot it worked out!! The demo really help me out too! :)

Answer (score -1):

Could you please write your entire component/Class? Where did you inject your script? if you did in the static html you are going to need window.google.

I wrote an example for you, remember to inject your script with API key in public/index.html

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new window.google.maps.Map(this.map, {
      center: { lat: 41.3851, lng: 2.1734 },
      mapTypeControl: false,
      zoom: 14
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{ width: "600px", height: "600px" }}
          ref={e => (this.map = e)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping markymark. But this was to get around the Create-React-App's method of using script tags in the public/index.html. CRA doesn't read script tags as expected with other projects.